# Is this a valid way for ASP.NET web app and wpf desktop app to access the same database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

.NET framework newbie here!
If I require an ASP.NET web app and a wpf desktop app to share a database, would it be achievable simply by using the same connection string in both projects? I am hosting the website locally. Or is this an over simplification?

I understand I could develop an API and host it as a web service and then let that do all the heavy lifting for me. But if everything is hosted locally and all I'm doing is having a little fun with these technologies then this is not absolutely necessary, correct?

Comment: It depends on what database you use. If that is single file based database (like sqlite or sql server compact) - you may have trouble using it from multiple processes. Otherwise it should be fine.

Comment: Should I only worry if my Flat file database is stupendously massive and I have not properly avoided deadlocks or corruptions? Or are you predicting some other issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from using the same database for multiple applications, just make sure your update, insert or delete commands do not cause a deadlock or data corruptions. This can be achieved in several ways, such as locking a database object before updating or deleting it.